# Extjs date picker. Issue highlighting dates on month change

Tags: extjs

I am highlighting a number of dates in a month when the date picker is shown. This is done by adding a highlightDates function to the Picker component

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.field.Picker, {

    highlightDates: function (picker, dates) {

        if (Ext.isEmpty(dates)) return;
        for(var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
            var t = new Date(dates[i].date),
                dtMillis = t.getTime(),
                offset = t.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000,
                dt = dtMillis + offset,
                cells = picker.cells.elements;  

            for (var c = 0; c < cells.length; c++) {
                var cell = Ext.fly(cells[c]);
                if (cell.dom.firstChild.dateValue == dt) {
                    cell.addCls('cell-highlight');
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The dates object passed into the function above is a variable set from an Ajax call in the controller.

```
getDates: function (cmp) {
    var me = this;
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'someurl',
        success: function (response) {
            me.specificDates = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText).specificDates;
        }
    });
}
```

The controller also contains a function which the date picker expand listener will call.

```
setDatesToHighlight: function(picker){  
    picker.highlightDates(picker.picker,this.specificDates);
}
```

Finally, this is called when the date picker is made visible using the expand listener

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'datefield',
    editable: false,
    listeners: {
        expand: 'setDatesToHighlight'
    }
}]
```

This is all working fine until i change the month in the picker. I cannot seem to trigger the setDatesToHighlight controller function again so the selected months dates get highlighted.

I was thinking i could override the update method on the picker but i am having difficulty obtaining the dates object i need to pass to the highlightDates function.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fire an event on every update, by overriding `Ext.picker.Date` instead of `Ext.form.field.Picker` and adding an override for the `update` function like:

```
Ext.override(Ext.picker.Date, {

    update: function (e) {
        var res = this.callParent(arguments);

        if (!this.pickerField) {
            return res;
        }

        this.pickerField.fireEvent('update', this);

        return res;
    },

    highlightDates: function (picker, dates) {
       . . .
    }
});
```

Now you can change the listener from `expand` to `update`.

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1l94

Comment: Thank you very much, you have really helped me and now my week will begin well :-)